# Classification of Frobenius algebras of small dimensions

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra

Despite (commutative) Frobenius algebras over a field $K$ being a very popular class of algebraic objects, it seems no attempt of classification (up to $K$-algebra isomorphism) for them has been attempted yet. While in nearly every book on group theory, you can find a classification of groups of small order, no such classification of Frobenius algebras of small dimension seems to exist in the literature (despite there being at least 3 books on Frobenius algebras).

We can assume that they are local and of the form $K[x_1,...,x_r]/I$, where being Frobenius means here (without loss of generality, assuming they are local and split) that $J^n \subseteq I \subseteq J^2$ for $J=<x_1,...,x_r>$ and that there is a unique 1-dimensional ideal in $K[x_1,...,x_r]/I$, or equivalently a "unique" non-zero polynomial of highest degree survives in $K[x_1,...,x_r]/I$.

In particular it seems to be unknown whether there are only finitely many Frobenius algebras of a given vector space dimension and whether their classification is independet of the given field.

This motivates the following question:

> Question: Can we give a classification of all Frobenius algebras (up to isomorphism of $K$-algebras) of vector space dimension $d$ for small $d$ (lets say $1 \leq d \leq 10$)? In particular is there a computer algebra system that can do this in case the field is finite, lets say with two or three (to have signs) elements?

Here a start:

$d=1$: We only have $K$.

$d=2$: We only have $K[x]/(x^2)$.

$d=3$: We only have $K[x]/(x^3)$.

$d=4$: We have $K[x]/(x^4)$ and $K[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$. (there is also $K[x,y]/(xy,x^2-y^2)$ but should be isomorphic to $K[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$?)

$d=5$: We have $K[x]/(x^5)$ and $K[x,y]/(xy,x^2-y^3)$ and $K[x,y,z]/(yz,xz,xy,y^2-z^2,x^2-z^2)$, did I forgot one?

$d=6$: We have $K[x]/(x^6)$,  $K[x,y]/(x^2,y^3)$, $K[x,y]/(xy,x^3-y^3)$ and $K[x,y,z]/(yz,xz,xy,y^2-z^3,x^2-z^3)$ but here Im not sure whether there are more (probably there are).

Comment: I'm confused by the definition of Frobenius algebra: on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_algebra) it is defined as an algebra endowed with some bilinear form, but then they say that some given algebra "is a Frobenius algebra". Is Frobenius algebra both used for "algebra endowed with a bilinear form with some properties", and for "an algebra that possesses at least one such bilinear from"?

Comment: @YCor I guess the most common definition is that it is one with at least one such bilinear form (at least that is the definition used in all books I know about the topic). An alternative equivalent definition is that it is a finite dimensional algebra $A$ such that $A \cong D(A)$ as right modules.

Comment: Thanks. It's a pity there are not two distinct words (like "metric" vs "metrizable") since both notions are useful.

Comment: Huh -- I've always heard it used in the sense of an algebra with certain extra structure (which can take various forms, for example coalgebra structure suitably compatible with the algebra structure). In other mathematics, there is the coinage "Frobenious", an adjectival form that suggests having a certain property -- maybe it would be good to adapt that here. :-)

Comment: @Todd The term has been used for an associative algebra with a certain property since the 1930s. Maybe the people who stole the name should think of a new one for the algebra with extra structure. :-)

Comment: I've sometimes seen "Frobenius algebra" for the structure and "algebra with the Frobenius property" for the property.

Comment: Or, following the HoTT book, "Frobenius algebra" and "merely Frobenius algebra."  The issue is whether there "exists" an A-mod iso $A \cong A^*$ or there "merely exists" such an iso.